# Linux: sockaddr_storage how to initialize it?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP based program which supports both `IPv4` and `IPv6`. So I used "`sockaddr_storage`" in the code.

In the ***client*** side, I need to pin the client TCP port to a particular one, so I need to bind the socket to that address.

```
struct sockaddr_storage local_addrs; //for local address

if (sc->domain == AF_INET) {
    (*(struct sockaddr_in*)&local_addrs).sin_family = AF_INET;
    (*(struct sockaddr_in*)&local_addrs).sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(INADDR_ANY);
    (*(struct sockaddr_in*)&local_addrs).sin_port = htons(tcp_port);
}
else{
    (*(struct sockaddr_in6*)&local_addrs).sin6_family = AF_INET6; 
    (*(struct sockaddr_in6*)&local_addrs).sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT);
    (*(struct sockaddr_in6*)&local_addrs).sin6_port = htons(tcp_port);
}

local_addr_size = sizeof(local_addrs);
if (( ret = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&local_addrs, local_addr_size)) < 0 ) {
    ....//error
}
```

How do I initialize the `struct sockaddr_storage local_addrs`? Do I need to malloc memory for this structure?

By the way, below line does not work yet. Still trying to find out how to bind the client sokcet to any possible IPv6 addresses.

```
(*(struct sockaddr_in6*)&local_addrs).sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT);
```

Comment: Why bind the *client* socket at all? That is highly unusual for TCP.

Comment: As I said in my question, I would like to bind the local TCP port to a specific one, for testing purpose. :)

Comment: what is `sc->domain` here?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have shown is basically the correct way to go, in that you need to type-cast a `sockaddr_storage` to the specific `sockaddr_...` type that you want to populate.

However, in the case of `sockaddr_in6`, the `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT` portion is wrong. Use this instead:

```
(*(struct sockaddr_in6*)&local_addrs).sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
```

`IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT` is a macro that can only be used in static declarations at compile-time, eg:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 in6 = {AF_INET6, port, 0, IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT, 0};
```

```
struct in6_addr addr = IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT;
```

`IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT` cannot be used in assignments at runtime, eg:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 in6;
in6.sin6_addr = IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT; // ERROR
```

```
struct in6_addr addr;
addr = IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT; // ERROR
```

`in6addr_any`, on the other hand, is a global variable that can be used in assignments at runtime.

And no, you do not need to `malloc` the `sockaddr_storage` structure.

That being said, I would suggest using some local variables to make the code easier to read:

```
if (sc->domain == AF_INET) {
    struct sockaddr_in *in4 = (struct sockaddr_in*) &local_addrs;
    in4->sin_family = AF_INET;
    in4->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // <-- inet_addr() is not needed for INADDR_ANY
    in4->sin_port = htons(tcp_port);
}
else {
    struct sockaddr_in6 *in6 = (struct sockaddr_in6*) &local_addrs;
    in6->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    in6->sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    in6->sin6_port = htons(tcp_port);
    /* note: sockaddr_in6 also has sin6_flowinfo and sin6_scope_id
       fields that you may have to fill, too...
    in6->sin6_flowinfo = ...;
    in6->sin6_scope_id = ...;
    */
}
```

Or, use a `union` instead:

```
union sockaddr_types {
    struct sockaddr_storage storage;
    struct sockaddr addr; 
    struct sockaddr_in in4;
    struct sockaddr_in6 in6;
};

union sockaddr_types local_addrs;

if (sc->domain == AF_INET) {
    local_addrs.in4.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local_addrs.in4.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    local_addrs.in4.sin_port = htons(tcp_port);
}
else {
    local_addrs.in6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    local_addrs.in6.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    local_addrs.in6.sin6_port = htons(tcp_port);
    /*
    local_addrs.in6.sin6_flowinfo = ...;
    local_addrs.in6.sin6_scope_id = ...;
    */
}

if ((ret = bind(sockfd, &local_addrs.addr, sizeof(local_addrs))) < 0) {
    //error...
}
```

Either way, you should also consider zeroing out the entire `sockaddr_storage` to pre-fill unused fields before then populating what you need:

```
memset(&local_addrs, 0, sizeof(local_addrs));
```